# PHP empty username/password input

Tags: html

I'm new to PHP so I'm obviously not good at it. what I want to do is to give an error to the user if they click on submit without filling the inputs(name/username/password)
here is what I did until now:

```
$fullname = ($_POST['fullname']);
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);
if(empty($fullname)){
echo ('Please fill the blank spaces');
}
```

(not sure echo is a good code for alerting)

The HTML:

```
<article>
    <form id="signform" method="post" action="signup.php" autocomplete="off">
        <input name="fullname" placeholder="Your FullName">
        <input name="username" placeholder="UserName">
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input class="Submit" type="button"  onclick="location.href='index.html';" value="Signup" />

    </form>
</article>
```

So it's not doing anything like if I don't fill any of the inputs I can press Submit and signup which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Use operator to check the string. `if($fullname!=""){}` like this. And you can also check input on user end using `required` in input field.

Comment: _Use operator to check the string..._ Why should he? @ZaidBinKhalid

Comment: If you don't want people to be able to click a button before all the required inputs are filled in, then you will have to resort to `javascript` to solve this issue

Comment: Please define `give an error`?

Comment: Is your PHP verification on the **signup.php** ?

Comment: @AymDev Yes It is

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I mean showing a message that you have to fill username or something like that..

Comment: so It's not completely possible with PHP?

Comment: Oh right, your "submit" is not what it should be

Comment: @DarkBee Nope, HTML attributes like `required` are working well for that purpose too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `type="submit"` for button and redirect to desired page after validating in php.

I suggest you to use like:

```
<article>
    <form id="signform" method="post" action="signup.php" autocomplete="off">
        <input name="fullname" placeholder="Your FullName">
        <input name="username" placeholder="UserName">
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input class="Submit" type="submit" value="Signup" />

    </form>
</article>
```

Comment: Tnx! I didn't pay attention to that.